# Trying to connect through cl

Tags: networking, command-line

I am trying with:

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid mynetwork key 4bare2011

$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid mynetwork key 4bare2011 mode Managed
```

and similar combinations. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

The key is right and works for other clients. But it doesn't get accepted. s:4bare2011 is also getting an error message. ddddddddd is accepted (but is wrong). It looks like the system only accepts hex, but converting the key above to hex also didn't help.

How can I connect, without changing the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using `iwconfig` and `wpasupplicant` "by hand" is to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add a stanza like

```
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.x.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.x.1
    wpa-ssid mynetwork
    wpa-psk  4bare2011
```

or

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid mynetwork
    wpa-psk  4bare2011
```

You can then connect with

```
ifup wlan0
```

and disconnect with

```
ifdown wlan0
```

This still uses `wpasupplicant` but it's transparent to you.

For more information on the different fields you can use, read [`interfaces(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/interfaces.5.html)

This alternative also opens up all sorts of interesting possibilities using [interface mapping](http://addisu.taddese.com/blog/mapping-in-linux-network-interfaces/)

Comment: Still, this works when I set the router to wpa, but Ubuntu seems to have a problem when it comes down to connect to wpa2.

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi network most likely uses WPA authentication, not the obsolete and insecure WEP. For WPA (WPA2, etc...), you cannot set the key directly using `iwconfig` because there is a higher level protocol that must be observed. For WPA, you need to run the [wpasupplicant](http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/) software.

Most operating system distributions provide a supported method for correctly starting wpasupplicant so that most end users don't need to worry about it manually.